# Erro: "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp, syntax-error

Estou a obter o seguinte erro quando tempo realizar uma consulta para inserir dados numa tabela na base-de-dados:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''nome','quantidade','codigo') VALUES ('Açúcar Refinado', '2','')' at line 1

**O meu código:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbnm = "carrinho";

$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
$banco = mysql_select_db($dbnm,$con) or die(mysql_error());
if (!$banco)
    die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> <br> ".mysql_error());

$nome = 'Açúcar Refinado';
$quantidade = '2';

$query = "INSERT INTO orcamento('nome','quantidade','codigo') 
VALUES ('$nome', '$quantidade','')";

mysql_query($query,$con) or die ("Não foi Possivel inserir <br>". mysql_error());

echo "Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!<br>Agradecemos a atenção.";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

Os nomes dos campos não precisam nem podem levar aspas, apenas os `VALUES`:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO orcamento (nome, quantidade, codigo) 
VALUES ('$nome', '$quantidade', '')";
```

Caso precise usar um nome reservado, então use [backticks operator](http://pt2.php.net/operators.execution) `` ` `` ao invés das aspa simples:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO orcamento (`nome`, `quantidade`, `codigo`) 
VALUES ('$nome', '$quantidade', '')";
```

Comment: Vlw, obrigado pela sua resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Não se usa aspas `'` simples nos nomes dos campos e sim crase  ``` `` ```

Quando algum campo tem o nome como uma palavra reservada como por exemplo um campo de decrição de um produto ser chamado apenas de `desc`, nesse caso é obrigatorio o uso de crase.

Seu insert deve ficar assim

```
INSERT INTO orcamento(`nome`, `quantidade`,`codigo`) VALUES ('$nome', '$quantidade','')";
```

Lembre que as funções mysql_* foram descontinuadas é altamente recomendado que vc use o [PDO](https://www.php.net/PDO) ou [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) e preparedStatements para evitar sql injection.

Recomendo a leitura dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-nao-devemos-usar-funcoes-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode também fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO orcamento SET nome='$nome', quantidade='$quantidade' ";
```

Não coloque o campo código se ele for auto incremento.